# Django 1.4 tests not working on sqlite3

Tags: django, unit-testing, sqlite

I am getting this error after upgrading to django 1.4 while running tests using sqlite:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Problem installing fixture '/home/devasia/pyserver/project/mysite/app/fixtures/test_data.json':        Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 196, in handle
obj.save(using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
  models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 529, in save_base
 rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 557, in _update
 return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 986, in   execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: Could not load auth.Permission(pk=31): columns content_type_id, codename are not unique


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.011s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This is my sample test case:

```
class CheckTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data.json']
    def test_check(self):
        c = Client()
        c.login(username = 'test', password = 'test')
```

The fixtures are not that of old version. I have created this fixture using django 1.4 starting from 'syncdb' command. The tests are running well if I use postgresql as my test database(the tests run really slow). 
Did I miss something while upgrading? I found this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14731 but couldn't resolve the issue. (Please note that the only code/data from old project is the models)

Thanks

Comment: Please put the relevant bits of your code/output here.

Comment: You have recreated DB in SQLite so your content_types and auth_permissions have different IDs. Fixture is probably trying to reference that data and fails. Patch up your fixture with correct references.